# Как сохранить данные с таймера в Pagination JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется 5 страниц и таймер. Задача состоит в том, чтобы сохранить в итоге время, проведённое пользователем на каждой странице.

Т.е., когда произойдёт клик на следующую страницу, то счётчик обнулится и начнёт отсчёт сначала. А данные о проведенном времени сохранятся в переменную для каждой страницы

```js
var timer = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  timer++;
  $('.timer').text(timer);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="timer">0</div>

<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  <a class="active" href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Как бы это реализовать и вывести на отдельной странице в конце? То есть:

1. страница 1 - время 1 мин 10 сек
2. страница 2 - время 1 мин 
   и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записывай все в локальную память браузера, иначе при переходе между страницами переменную ты сразу же потеряешь.
Запись:

```
localStorage.setItem('page-1', JSON.stringify(timer_value));
```

Чтение (используй на финальной странице):

```
var page1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('page-1'));
```

Если у тебя перехода между страницами нет и ты рассматриваешь вариант с табами на одной страницу то первым делом почитай про замыкания и оператор let.

В прочем в самом примитивном виде можно обойтись и без них.

```js
var timer = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  timer++;
  $('.timer').text(timer);
}, 1000);

var data = {
  'page-1': 0,
  'page-2': 0,
  'page-3': 0,
  'page-4': 0,
  'page-5': 0,
}


function updateResult(){
$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(data));
}

$(".page").click(function(e){
  if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){ 
    data[$(".page.active").attr("data-val")]+=timer;
    timer = 0; 
    updateResult();
    $(".page.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="timer">0</div>

<div class="pagination">
  <a class="prev" href="#" disabled>&laquo;</a>
  <a class="page active" href="#" data-val="page-1">1</a>
  <a class="page" href="#" data-val="page-2">2</a>
  <a class="page" href="#" data-val="page-3">3</a>
  <a class="page" href="#" data-val="page-4">4</a>
  <a class="page" href="#" data-val="page-5">5</a>
  <a class="next" href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>

<h6>Result</h6>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: табы на одной странице. Замыкания и let - что именно прочитать?

Comment: @DmitryNikitin добавил простенький пример отображающий общую идею, но если хочешь понимать js, то обязательно ознакомься с этим материалом https://learn.javascript.ru/closures

Comment: здесь код работает, пробовал перенести к себе - таймер идёт, а пагинация и вывод Result не работают - не понимаю, почему.

Comment: хм. скинь полный вариант страницы если есть возможность. ну или попробуй запустить в разных браузерах, убедись что ничего не закешировалось и что ты подключил jquery (хотя если таймер работает то точно подключил). В коде что-нибудь менял?

Comment: скрипт был у меня в <body>, вынес - заработало.

Comment: как бы реализовать, чтобы данные о времени и слайдах "улетели" на отдельную php-страницу?

Comment: @DmitryNikitin поясни что ты подразумеваешь под улетали на страницу? Улетали на сервер по заданному url - делай запросы соответственно в параметрах указывая текущее значение таймера, улетали на страницу в плане когда на нее перейдешь позже - или использовать базу данных или localstorage для хранения переменных. Опишите задачу подробнее, сейчас откровенно говоря не понятно.

Comment: при переходе на страницу позже, используя базу данных. интересен сам механизм записи данных таймера в базу. наводящий пример необходим.

Comment: базу данных или localstorage? если бд, то все зависит от того какую и на чем вообще серверная часть крутиться.

Comment: бд на Битрикс .

Comment: о, ну тут гугли про битрикс и как работать с бд. я с cms не работал.